# Z Transform Matlab Ezplot Error

Tags: matlab, plot, transform, matlab-figure

First of all, I'm using sym, so I need a step (Heaviside) function. I know there exists a `heaviside(t)` in Matlab, so I'm using that.

Now, let's say I have function: `x = -2^(-n+1)*heaviside(n-2)` with `syms n` before. Now:

```
X = ztrans(x);   // z transform
x = iztrans(X);  // inverse z transform
```

(This should return the original x function)

This returns `x = kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0)/4 - 2*(1/2)^n + 2*kroneckerDelta(n, 0)`

When I try to plot `x` now, by using `ezplot(x)` it returns a bunch of errors:

```
Error using inlineeval (line 15)
Error in inline expression ==> kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0)./4 - 2.*(1./2).^n + 2.*kroneckerDelta(n, 0)
 Undefined function 'kroneckerDelta' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in inline/feval (line 34)
        INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in ezplotfeval (line 52)
    z = feval(f,x(1));

Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 467)
    [y, f, loopflag] = ezplotfeval(f, x);
```

How can I plot the function x or stop these errors from appearing? I've only used Matlab inherent functions, dunno what to do...

Comment: it works in mupad. you may want to run your code there

Answer (score 0):

I bet `ezplot` works by evaluating the function for some real-values substituted into the symbolic variable `n`. In this case, `kroneckerDelta` only accepts integer valued (non-double) inputs. So an idea is to use `subs` to put integers into `kroneckerDelta`.

```
x =

kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0)/4 - 2*(1/2)^n + 2*kroneckerDelta(n, 0)

>> subs(x,-5:5)

ans =

[ -64, -32, -16, -8, -4, 0, 0, -1/4, -1/4, -1/8, -1/16]

>> plot(-5:5,ans)
```